# Get all directories with only one specific file inside

Tags: rsync, scp, sftp

I have a series of directories on a remote server (D1, D2, D3,...) and each directory contains multiple files (f1, f2, f3) with the same names.

What I have on the remote Server:
D1: f1, f2, f3 
D2: f1, f2, f3
D3: f1, f2, f3
.
.
.

What I want on the local machine:
D1: f1 
D2: f1
D3: f1
.
.
.

I need to get all directories with only f1 inside (D1/f1, D2/f1,
D3/f1,...). I know SFTP doesn't support regular expressions but is there an alternative way to do that? If that's not possible in SFTP, is there a way to do it using scp or rsync?

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy only the f1 file from these directories? Or that you want to copy the f1 file only when it's the sole file in a directory?

Comment: On the destination (local machine) what name/s do you want to give to f1 to differentiate each copy? Or did you want to copy the directories too?

Comment: I need to copy only f1. All directories contain 3 files (f1,f2,f3). So I need to have a local copy of all those directories but only containing f1. I also updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rsync` command can do this

```
rsync --dry-run -avR remoteHost:'/path/to/./D*/f1' /path/to/target
```

Just as for `ssh`, the `remoteHost` component could be `remoteUser@remoteHost` if necessary. The `/./` point in the source path marks the place from where directories will be included in the copy. `/path/to/target` could be `.` if you want to write to the current directory.

Example

```
mkdir -p /tmp/src/D{1,2,3} /tmp/dst
touch /tmp/src/D{1,2,3}/f{1,2,3}

rsync -avR localhost:'/tmp/src/./D*/f1' /tmp/dst/
ls -R /tmp/dst
```